# display:none links clickable on iPhone

Tags: jquery, wordpress, mobile

On my website (which is run through WordPress), I have a series of clickable image thumbnails. When you hover over a thumbnail, a grey box appears over the thumbnail. This grey box that appears is a clickable link, but only 80% of the grey box is clickable.

My issue is how an iPhone reacts to this box when it is clicked. When you click anywhere outside of the 80% region (the clickable region), the grey box appears. This is great. But if you click anywhere within this 80% region, you are automatically brought to the link, instead of the grey box appearing. This may seem a bit confusing in text form, so I drew a picture to showcase my issue: 
[image: iPhone Hover Problem]

So say you are on an iPhone, and you see a thumbnail you want to click on. If you click outside of the 80% region, the grey box appears just like it should.  But if you click within this 80% region (the region that is the actual link), then you get redirected to the external source without even seeing the grey hover box that should appear.  This is the problem.  I would like it to work just like how it works on a computer, so if you are on an iPhone and you click anywhere on a thumbnail, the grey hover box should always appear, not redirect you to the external link. Because this 80% region that links a user to an external source on an iphone is set to `display:none` and is essentially invisible to the user (until you hover over a thumbnail).  The user should not be able to click on a link they cannot see.

So how would I make it so that the hover grey box always appears when clicked on an iPhone, no matter where on a thumbnail a user clicks? Any suggestions or input would be great.

***Update:***

Here is the jquery that makes the grey divs appear (via `opacity`)

```
$( document ).ready( function() {
$('.entry-image').mouseover(function(){
    //show the box
    $(this).children('.thumbhover').stop().animate({opacity:1},300);
});

$('.entry-image').mouseleave(function(){
    //hide the box
    $(this).children('.thumbhover').stop().animate({opacity:0},500);
});
```

I also added `display:none` to my thumbhover divs in CSS and `show()` to the jquery so the divs are using not display as well as `opacity:0` and then when you hover over them, it hads a block display as well as a `opacity:1`

Comment: Can you set up a jsfiddle of the problem?

Comment: @roviuser I spent like 15 mins on a jsfiddle, but jsfiddle isn't working on the phone at the moment. Here is my website: motodz.com it's not done yet, but look at it on the phone and click outisde the regions in the diagram, and inside.. you'll see what I mean :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed this double tap / touch hover issue on the iPhone by making the clickable region `display:none;` and then making it visible again on hover via CSS. Like so..

```
.thumbhover {display:none;}

.entry-image:hover .thumbhoverimg {display:block !important;}
```

So I made the clickable region invisible, and then visible again when a user hovers over the "entry-image" div.  This seemed to fix the hover issue on the iPhone. :)

Comment: Given the fact that I made you realize you where not using `display:none` as you thought and that I also told you this solution, maybe you should consider upvoting my answer or any of my comments. This is how StackOverflow works ;)

Comment: @cprcrack You suggested that in a comment, not in your answer.  And even so, your comment involved changing the div to display none for a temporary time then changing it back in a split second. This involves jQuery. My answer that worked for myself is pure CSS. Although both ways of doing things involve display:none, my answer and your comment are two completely different methods. Mine worked for me, and I had no idea how to got about your solution. And also, I understand how SO works. ;)

Comment: I edited my answer two times to reflect that and try to help you. So actually it was in the answer. And I didn't tell you to mark my answer as "the answer", but to upvote it, the answer or just a comment, because it's obvious that it helped you. But I really don't care if you upvote me or not, I just thought you didn't think about it. If you tell me that you thought about it and decided on purpose that neither of my answer/comments were helpful at all, that's your decision. Keep doing that. And by the way, it definitely does not require jQuery, I hope you were trying to say Javascript.

Answer (score 0):

It **seems** that when the iPhone user touches the box, first the "hover" event gets fired (so the grey box is displayed always) and then the "click" event gets fired, so the user is directed to the link if within the 80% area. The problem is that this two events happen sequentially and immediately (unlike in the computer), so you cannot even see the grey box because the page is already being re-directed to a new page.

Have you tried also displaying the grey box on the link's onclick event? I mean, copying the styling procedure you do on the "hover" event and putting it in the link's "click" event.

**Update to answer your comment:**

You can detect if the user is on a mobile device with something such as this Javascript:

```
function isMobileDevices() {
    return navigator.userAgent.match(/Android|BlackBerry|iPhone|iPad|iPod|Opera Mini|IEMobile/i) !== null
}
```

And act differently in that case. For example, and this is pretty ugly, do the link opening via Javascript on the "click" event instead of using a real `<a>` link, but if we are in a mobile device, only open the link when it is the second or above time the user clicks it. For this, you will have to track every box status, little bit laborious.

Probably better alternative is to research about [touch events](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/Touch_events) and manage those events accordingly.

**Update**

Looking at your website's source, I can't see that your are using `display:none`, as you mentioned in your question. I see `opacity:0`, which is different. Have you tried really using `display:none` until you need to start animating the opacity?

Comment: Hi, thnaks for the answer. On the iPhone: I would like the user not to be redirected onclick. It would be ideal if the hover always came up no matter where the user clicks, and then they have to click it again to get redirected. Here is my website: motodz.com view it on a phone and click on a thumbnail to see what I'm talking about. :)

Comment: Tested on the iPhone. As I thought, the grey box is being shown (you can see it when you go back to the main page after opening a link in a new page. If you need "two touches" for the iPhone users that's a different thing. I have updated my answer.

Comment: Wow, I always thought I used display none, not opacity.  But opacity is essential because it creates the animated fade effect on hover in / out.  Is there any way we could get this working so you have to double tap like you were saying, while still making opacity work like it does?

Comment: Set `display:none`. Then, just before you make the call for the opacity animation from 0 to 1, put it back to `display:block`. And just after the animation from 1 to 0 is performed set it to `display:none` again. This should be easy for you to do. Then test it, because in fact I doubt this will work, but just to be sure. And if it doesn't, you have the "laborious" way I told you in my answer, that will for sure work.

Comment: you're right, the display none did not work, and to be honest I have no idea on how to go about your strategy. It seems a bit butchy.  But at this point i'm willing to try anything.. some extra help or code would be great. If not, I appreciate your input this far.

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to have the grey box appear, set a click event on the first element to make the grey box appear. Then set another click even on the grey box to take you wherever...

I made a demo:

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/newe1344/tzkK7/7/)

HTML:

```
<div id="box">
   <a class="link one" href="#first">First click</a>
   <a class="link two" href="#second">Second click</a>
</div>
```

And then your script:

```
$('.one').on('click', function(evt) {
    evt.preventDefault();
    console.log('clicked');
    $('.two').css({
      'top': '0px'
    });
});

$('.two').on('click', function(evt) {
   evt.preventDefault()
   // outside link
   alert("You clicked an outside link!");
});
```

Comment: He only wants two clicks (really finger touches) to be done when the user is on a mobile device. So, as I mentioned in my answer, this is a good way of proceeding but just in the cases the user is on a mobile device, so there is some Javascript logic needed there.

Comment: cprcrack said it right!  If there is any way you could get an answer so that the user has to click / touch twice on the phone for the hovers, that would be more than great! :)